# Define Implementation for abstract Object

Tags: java, class, dependency-injection, abstraction

I am looking for a way to do the following:

A Project :
Defines an abstract class that is called when some events happen (event handler if you will)
Defines the engine that will fire the events using the event handler above

B Project: 
Defines the implementation for the abstract class
Runs the engine.

How can i register the implementation class and make sure that is the one being called when the engine runs.

EDIT 1: By register i mean i must somehow define which is the implementation that should be called for that given abstract object

Sorry if the question isn't too clear, let me know if you need some more details

Comment: What do you mean by "register the implementation class"?

Comment: As far as I understand (maybe you can give some more clarification e.g. Pesudo Code) you would have to instantiate the actual B Project implementation as a reference to the A Project abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, you can have the name of the implementation passed in your A project (with a properties file or a Java system property).
Then you find this class in the classpath with `class.forName()` and instantiate it with `newInstance()`.

But you'd prefer using a framework like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or Spring, that will allow you to glue stuff together in a clean way.

Comment: The solution i implemented is based on your first sugestion, i had a look at Guice and may end up going for it, but for now this is enough thx

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
class A implements EventHandlerForB {
...
}

public class B {
  private EventHandlerForB eventHandler;

  public void registerEventHandler(EventHandlerForB eventHandler) {
    this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
  }
...
}

public interface EventHandlerForB {
...
}
```

Comment: Passing it thought the constructor is probably better for unicast.

Comment: This solution did require me to code the class that invokes the handler, which i am not doing. using your objects, in my problem class B would be closed and class A would be what i implement.

Answer (score 0):

there are several "patterns" that try to address this issue. Using only JDK (6 or above) classes you may want to take a look at [java.util.ServiceLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)